# Can a Pipe endpoint be shared between processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe, tornado

I have a setting where I use Tornado for handling web requests and queuing tasks to a bunch of Python processes. One of these processes is a control process, while the others are worker processes. I want to implement a functionality allowing the compute part of this server to be turned off, restarted and so on. This works perfectly when Tornado is ran as a single process. However, when using multiple server processes, that is:

```
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
server.bind(8888)
server.start(2)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

This spawns three processes (one control and two handlers). And when I decide to stop the compute processes I get an error:

```
AssertionError: can only join a child process
```

Which I interpret as a Tornado handler process trying to stop the compute processes, but the Tornado control one being their parent.

I am thinking about using pipes so I can send a stop message to the control compute process, however again, the question arises whether a Pipe endpoint can be shared between the 2 handler processes?

And as a second question, is my approach/architecture totally wrong and what could be a proper approach/architecture?

Comment: Ok, the first and obvious part - they can, but is it completely safe?

Comment: are you talking about using multiprocessing or starting completely separate processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to include more sample code to help with the `AssertionError`. But basically only the thread which creates a new thread or process can join it (as the message suggests).

Regarding `Pipe`s, you could create two Pipes (one for each sub-Process), since once the message is read by one, it won't be available for other. Items can be shared between `tornado.web.Handlers` with `tornado.web.RequestHandler.settings`.

However, keep in mind that a Handler is created for a request. But it sounds like you may be using them for background processing? If that is the case, you can simply share a Queue with them and 'poison' it.